# On which scheduler Task.ContinueWith() runs?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

Consider the following code:

```
// MyKickAssTaskScheduler is a TaskScheduler, IDisposable
using (var scheduler = new MyKickAssTaskScheduler())
{
    Task foo = new Task(() => DoSomething());
    foo.ContinueWith((_) => DoSomethingElse());
    foo.Start(scheduler);
    foo.Wait();
}
```

Is the `ContinueWith()` Task guaranteed to run on my scheduler? If not, which scheduler will it use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

StartNew, ContinueWith will default to TaskScheduler.Current, Current will return the Default scheduler, When not called from within a task(MSDN).

To avoid the default scheduler issue, you should always pass an explicit TaskScheduler to Task.ContinueWith and Task.Factory.StartNew.

[ContinueWith is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html)

Comment: Thanks. Is this a questionable design decision or am I missing something? Has anyone from TPL ever explained it?

Comment: @bavaza - new to me also started reading to get deep information about it

Comment: @bavaza, TPL's Stephen Toub provides some explanation here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/09/22/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5.aspx

Comment: @Noseratio - read it, but still skeptic about the validity of this behavior - I ran the first task on a non-default scheduler **for a reason**. Why did TPL decide the continuation, which is **always** sequential to my task, should run on another?

Comment: @bavaza, I addressed your comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31116891/1768303).

Answer (score 4):

> Is the ContinueWith() Task guaranteed to run on my scheduler? If not,
>   which scheduler will it use?

No, it will use the scheduler passed to the original `Task`. `ContinueWith` will default to use `TaskScheduler.Current`, in which case is the default thread-pool task scheduler. There is no propagation between your provided context to `task.Start` and the one used inside the continuation

[From the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,e71924f994d1bb54):

```
public Task ContinueWith(Action<Task> continuationAction)
{
    StackCrawlMark stackMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
    return ContinueWith(continuationAction, 
                        TaskScheduler.Current, 
                        default(CancellationToken),
                        TaskContinuationOptions.None, ref stackMark);
}
```

Comment: I ran some tests, and saw that my continuation runs on a different scheduler. I speculate this is because TaskScheduler.Current return the Default .Net Framework scheduler when called from within a task. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: my custom scheduler is a variant of the [StaTaskScheduler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx), and therefore uses an STA thread, which is not from the thread pool

Comment: @bavaza You're right, I did some testing and there's no flowing of the scheduler.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, but it [does flow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31116891/1768303) the ambient task scheduler :)

Comment: @Noseratio What does the ambient `TaskScheduler.Current` mean? Does it ever change from `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, it's the task scheduler which runs the currently executing task. Thus, it becomes ambient for any tasks createded via TPL API inside that task, where you don't specify the scheduler explicitly (except for `Task.Run`, which always uses `TaskScheduler.Default`). E.g., see the code in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> @Noseratio - read it, but still skeptic about the validity of this
>   behavior - I ran the first task on a non-default scheduler for a
>   reason. Why did TPL decide the continuation, which is always
>   sequential to my task, should run on another?

I agree - this is not the best design - but I imaging that defaulting to `TaskScheduler.Current` is there for `ContinueWith` to be consistent with `Task.Factory.StartNew`, which defaults to `TaskScheduler.Current` too, in the first place. Stephen Toub [does explain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/09/22/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5.aspx) the latter design decision:

> In many situations, that’s the right behavior.  For example, let’s say
>   you’re implementing a recursive divide-and-conquer problem, where you
>   have a task that’s supposed to process some chunk of work, and it in
>   turn subdivides its work and schedules tasks to process those chunks. 
>   If that task was running on a scheduler representing a particular pool
>   of threads, or if it was running on a scheduler that had a concurrency
>   limit, and so on, you’d typically want those tasks it then created to
>   also run on the same scheduler.

Thus, `ContinueWith` uses the current (ambient) `TaskScheduler.Current` of whatever task is currently executing at the moment you call `ContinueWith`, rather than the one of the antecedent task. In case this is a problem for you and you cannot explicitly specify the task scheduler, there is a workaround. You can make your custom task scheduler to be the ambient one for a particular scope, like this:

```
using (var scheduler = new MyKickAssTaskScheduler())
{
    Task<Task> outer = new Task(() => 
    {
       Task foo = new Task(() => DoSomething());
       foo.ContinueWith((_) => DoSomethingElse());
       foo.Start(); // don't have to specify scheduler here
       return foo;
    }

    outer.RunSynchronously(scheduler);
    outer.Unwrap().Wait();
}
```

Note that `outer` is `Task<Task>`, hence there's `outer.Unwrap()`. You could also do `outer.Result.Wait()`, but there's some semantic difference, especially if you used `outer.Start(scheduler)` instead of `outer.RunSynchronously(scheduler)`.

Comment: Cool trick :) . Still, I think I'll stick to either explicitly specifying the scheduler or avoid `ContinueWith()` altogether...

Comment: @bavaza, if you can avoid `ContinueWith` altogether and use `await` instead, that'd be the best decision. You can model your scheduler around a thread with custom `SynchronizationContext` (which would make it `await`-friendly) and simply do `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.